# TDA2050 LM3886 LTSpice Model

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I was looking for some time to find a TDA2055 or LM3886 LTSpice, but I wasn't able to find any, so I was wondering is there a way to get TDA2050 (or other equivalent op amp) LTSpice Model for circuit simulation?

Comment: IIRC, there's some `TDA20xx` model in the LTspice Yahoo group's file section. Subscribing is needed, though.

Comment: Can you share it? :-)

Comment: I had, have, and, most likely, will not need such a model, so you're welcome to go to https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/ltspice/info and get it yourself. Registration is a simple mail confirmation and unregistering is done easily.